# How to see firebase analytics events and filter item name?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

[image: my code]

Suppose I call `logContentAnalytics(navigation-drawer)` . How can i see this parameter in firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

as described in this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en&ref_topic=9267641) you can find your events under Analytics > Events section on the left side menu. if you mark some events as "Conversions", you can find them under Analytics > Conversions section.

Comment: I am asking where will I see ‘navigation-drawer’ which I paased in the method.